# Increasing qubit limit in Qiskit for benchmarking

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, transpile

I am aware that each backend in Qiskit has a qubit limit. Across all backends in `Aer`, the limit is 24. When we employ `ibmq_simulators` then the the limit increases to 32. My requirement is not simulation but only to benchmark gate counts.

For counting gates I perform the following:

```py
ALL_GATES = ["h", "t", "tdg", "s", "sdg", "cx", "rz"]
self.backend = AerSimulator()
tqc = transpile(
    circuit, self.backend, optimization_level=3, basis_gates=ALL_GATES
)
return self.skd(tqc)
```

I want to perform transpilation to get the gates and then decompose them using `SolovayKitaev` to get gate counts. The backend I use has a qubit limit, is there an alternative backend that does not have any? I do not intend to run these circuits, I just want to get the number of gates.

**Edit:** I realised that I can remove the backend and run `transpile`. I hope that this solution is sufficient. If there is an alternative solution please suggest, else I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the `backend` argument from your `transpile()` call and that will remove the limitation. The `backend` argument is used to tell the qiskit transpiler that you're targeting a specific backend and it will map your circuit given the constraints expressed in that backend's `Target` (https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.transpiler.Target). The primary (but not only) constraints the transpiler is concerned with are connectivity and the supported instructions/gates. In the case of selecting an ideal Aer simulator (via `AerSimulator()`) without any noise there are no connectivity constraints, just the limit in the number of qubits, and the work of the transpiler is solely a function of translating the input circuit's gates to match the basis gates; which for Aer is a much larger superset than `ALL_GATES`. However, by setting `basis_gates` as an argument in addition to backend you're overriding that and the transpiler will be ignoring `AerSimulator`'s basis gates. So you can safely remove the `backend` argument in this case.

It is important to mention here that this isn't a general solution, as for real backends or potentially other simulators this will result in an invalid transpiler output for a given backend. But in the case of using aer like this without a noise model it should work fine. Also, the `Target` model the backend's use support more involved instruction models like heterogeneous gates on different qubits so this solution is really only applicable to a bare `AerSimulator()` without any options set.

As an aside the number of qubits limit set on the aer backend should be dynamically set based on the chosen simulation method and the amount of available memory on your system. 24 seems awfully low as a limit though because for a statevector simulation that is ~268 MB of memory and a 25 qubit simulation would require ~537 MB of memory.